Keep getting error Cannot use JSX unless the '--jsx' flag is provided
I'm getting the following error in my vite react app when I want to run my jest tests;

Cannot use JSX unless the '--jsx' flag is provided.

jest.config.mjs
export default {
  rootDir: './',
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(ts|tsx)$': 'ts-jest',
  },
  globals: {
    'ts-jest': {
      tsconfig: 'tsconfig.json', // Explicitly point to your tsconfig
    },
  },
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1',
    '\\.(css|less|scss|sass)$': 'identity-obj-proxy',
  },
};

ts.config.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "tsBuildInfoFile": "./node_modules/.tmp/tsconfig.app.tsbuildinfo",
    "target": "ES6",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["ES2020", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx", // For React 17+ and React 18
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "./src/types", 
      "./node_modules/@types", 
      "../common/types",
    ],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    /* Path aliases */
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"],
      "@common/*": ["../common/*"]
    },

    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "moduleDetection": "force",
    "noEmit": true,

    /* Linting */
    "strict": false,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "allowJs": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*", 
    "../common/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}

I tried changing the value of "jsx": "react-jsx" and still no luck as stated in this question.
